# How to run specific test cases from a test suite using Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am new to Robot and am learning to write logic and test cases.

I have a test suite, "mytestsuite.robot", which has a lot of test cases. I have a couple of errors in one of my test cases.

How do I run just that specific test case since I don't want to run the whole test suite again?

#### File mytestsuite.robot

```
testcase1
....
....
testcase2
....
....
testcase3
....
....
testcase4
....
....
```

Say test case 3 failed, and I want to just rerun test case 3.

I tried to use:

```
pybot mytestsuite.robot -t testcase3
```

But I get an error.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You want to use the option `-t` or `--test`, but the option goes *before* the name of the file rather than after. This should work:

```
robot -t testcase1 mytestsuite.robot
```

The order of the command line arguments is covered in the user guide under a section titled [Starting test execution](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#starting-test-execution), and is also available at the command line with the `--help` option (e.g. `pybot --help`)

Be aware that the specific file name is optional. You could use only:
robot -t testcase1 .

Where  "." means look for all files that contains the specified test. Robot will do the hard work of finding the specific test.

You can use also willcard as * in the begining or finish of the test name, to match easily a test or to run multiple tests.

robot -t "testcase1*" .

Will match all tests that begin with "testcase1" in current folder.

The user guide has a section titled [Selecting test cases](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#selecting-test-cases) which covers this subject.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to run *single* test case in Robot Framework, use the below example.

Syntax:  `robot -t "Test Case Name" Test Suite Name` 
Example: `robot - t "PON Type Test Case" Aquarium_Project.robot`

If you want to run *all* the test cases in Robot Framework, use the below example

Syntax: `robot  Test Suite Name` 
Example: `robot Aquarium_Project.robot`

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `__init__.robot` files that have setups and teardowns, you cannot directly call a test from a test file if you have nested directory structures like the following:

```
|-- foo
    |-- bar.robot
```

And the bar.robot file has a test case named baz, in this case, you can do the following:

```
robot --test 'foo.bar.baz' foo
```

With deeper nesting:

```
|-- foo
    |-- bar
        |-- baz.robot

robot --test 'foo.bar.baz.*' foo
```

You can use `*` (asterisk) to run all test cases in the foo.bar.baz suite.

Answer (score 0):

Late post, but in case someone looks for this in future, you can also use the concept of `Tags`. With Robot Framework you can tag your test suites and test cases. I will restrict myself to Test-based tags for your question. For rest you can give a read to - https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#tagging-test-cases

In your case:
File mytestsuite.robot

```
testcase1
...
...
testcase2
...
...
testcase3
[Tags] | temp
...
...
testcase4
...
...
```

You can add multiple number of tags to any test case. Use the `--include` (also used as `-i`) robot option to specify which tag you want to run. In this case:

```
robot --include temp mytestsuite.robot
```

OR

```
robot --i temp mytestsuite.robot
```

Comment: Last code snippet should be `robot -i temp mytestsuite.robot`